# Recovering the message that is digitally signed not only the address

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, signature

Is there a way to recover a digitally signed message in a smart contract?

`ecrecover(msgHash, v, r, s)`

returns the address that signed the msgHash. I am looking for something that can return the `msgHash` itself which can be decrypted using the provided public key from the signature.